# Gmail keyboard shortcut for "Display images below"

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Gmail for the "Display images below" or "always display images from" links in emails?

Comment: This is definitely needed, I keep hoping it will be added, but it never does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at this time.  A list of existing keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594).

Answer (score 0):

No shortcut, but if you've previously okayed images then it should show automatically if they send something in the future with images.

> #### [Display images from certain senders](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=145919&ctx=cb)
>
> If someone you've sent email at least twice sends you a message with images in it, you’ll see the image by default (because the people in this group are likely people you know and trust).

Comment: Naked links aren't particularly useful. Can you include why this link is an answer to the question.